# React Firebase UseEffect Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I've got a user bar component directly adjacent to my navbar, showing avatar and display name (user details saved within a userid-named doc). I followed the firestore documentation for real time updates. Placed inside a use effect hook, which has a dependency array, but is firing repetitively, firing off about 4,000 calls a minute per logged in user).

I really just want the snapshot to update when a user updates their display name or avatar. (found on a different form component)

I console logged every useEffect hook in my project to narrow it down to this component. Is there something about the dependency array causing this? Is there a better way to write this? Thanks!

```
export default function UserBar() {
    const { user } = useAuthContext()
    const [me, setMe] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {

    //user real-time subscription for avatar and displayname
    const auth = getAuth()
    const fireUser = auth.currentUser

    const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", fireUser.uid), (doc) => {

        if (doc.exists()) {
            setMe(doc.data())
            console.log('looking for duplicate - userbar unsub')
        } else {
            console.log("No such document!")
        }
    })
    return () => unsub()
  }, [me])

  return ( 
    <>
        {user && (
            <div className="user-bar">
                <p className="oneHunid">Welcome
                    <span className="bold">&nbsp;&nbsp;{user.displayName}!</span>
                </p>
                <Avatar src={me.photoURL} />
            </div>
        )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to have `[me]` as a dependency when inside the `useEffect()` you call `setMe()`.  That leads to an infinite loop:

1. `me` gets a new value, so render
2. `me` has a new value, so run `useEffect()`
3. `useEffect()` calls `setMe()`
4. go to # 1

Based on the above, it looks like what you really want is to have your `useEffect()` be dependent on the value of `auth.currentUser`.  So get that value *outside* of the useEffect() and then check to be sure it is not `null`.  If it is not `null`, then start the `onSnapshot()` listener.

BTW: if it would be of help, check out the [user profiles with Firebase Auth](https://github.com/gregfenton/react-and-user-profiles-with-firebase-auth-and-firestore) project I developed.  In particular, check out the `FirebaseProvider.js` which is where I configure the Firebase project and get all of its services, and `AuthProvider.js` which provides login, logout, registration and "user profile".